# How to call a method with its key names as string variable (determine dynamically key arguments)?

Tags: methods, ruby-on-rails-3.2, metaprogramming

This is a Ruby question though I use it in a Rails context.

I need to call a method where I use string variables to assign values to its keys (parameter names).

For instance I got :

```
MyRailsModelClass.where(key_of_my_method: my_value)
```

I want to make this more dynamic.
I can create a MyRailsModelClass like this "my_rails_model_class".classify

I need to make key_of_my_method more dynamic and replace it with a variable.
I'm thinking about something like :

```
"my_rails_model_class".classify.where(my_key.to_sym => my_value)
```

Does anybody has a clue ?
Thanks

Comment: Absolutely, this will work.  Are you having trouble doing this?

Comment: Yes doesn't seem to work with rbuy version 1.9 key syntax (without the "=>")

Comment: Correct, you can't use the JSON-type syntax because the symbol is only dynamically referenced (via `to_sym`).  Is there a reason you can't use the rocket syntax `=>`?

Comment: As the syntax without colons is new with ruby 1.9, I was anticipating that maybe in the future the "arrow" syntax would become deprecated.

Comment: No, there is no such idea on the table at this time - the colon syntax was introduced to enable simpler, friendlier code for common cases.  It does not replace the rocket syntax since it does not cover all cases; rather only where the key is a static symbol.  For keys that are dynamically assigned symbols, or any other type (Fixnum, String, younameit), the rocket syntax is the only one that works.

Comment: Thanks for those clarifications !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, classify method is not enough. You need to constantize before to apply any class method.

I solved it this way (because it is much more efficient; while classify do call many more methods : camelize(singularize(table_name.to_s.sub() ) :

```
"my_rails_model_class".camelize.constantize.where("my_key".to_sym == my_value).first
```

but you could do it the longuer way :

```
"my_rails_model_class".classify.constantize.where("my_key".to_sym == my_value).first
```